# Slider controlling NSScroller

Tags: swift, macos, scroll

I'm using NSScrollview with a grid inside. Everything is working and the scroller bar moves the grid view as anticipated. I now wish to control the scroll from lets say a slider. That works fine and moves the scroller. This unfortunately does not actually scroll the view. but does if you use the scroller. I have tried NSScrollerNoPart which i thought it might need activating. I have look on all the IB windows to find something that might turn it on. Thanks for reding

heres my code Swift 3 Xcode8 OSX MacOS not IOS

```
 //  MainWindowController.swift

import Cocoa

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {


    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: NSScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var containerView: NSView!
    @IBOutlet weak var gridView: GridGUI!
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollbar: NSScroller!

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        //NSScrollerNoPart = true

    }//EO Overide


    @IBAction func mySlider(_ sender: AnyObject) {//set to min 0 max 1

        let data = sender.floatValue
        print("Data",data)

        scrollbar.floatValue = Float(data!)

        gridView.display()
        scrollView.display()
        containerView.display()

    }//eo slider

}//EnD oF thE wORld


class GridGUI: NSView {

    var xPosArray = [Int]()
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {

        //--------- BACKGROUND
        let back1 = NSMakeRect(0,0,9000,482)
        let back1Color = NSColor(red: 0.3, green: 0.3, blue: 0.5, alpha: 0.2)
        let back1Path: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: back1)
        back1Color.set()
        back1Path.fill()

        var gridY:CGFloat = 0.0 //Vertical position
        var gridYGray:CGFloat = 0.9

        for i in 0..<225{
            if (i % 16 == 0){gridYGray = 0.2}
            else{gridYGray = 0.7}

            //--------- VERTICAL GRID LINES
            let gridY1 = NSMakeRect(gridY,0, 4.0,480)
            let gridY1Color = NSColor(red: gridYGray, green: gridYGray, blue: gridYGray, alpha: 1.0)
            let gridY1Path: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: gridY1)
            gridY1Color.set()
            gridY1Path.fill()
            gridY = gridY + 40.0
        }

        //HORIZONTAL GRID LINES
        var gridX:CGFloat = 0.0
        for _ in 0..<25{
            //--------- HORIZONTAL GRID LINES
            let gridX1 = NSMakeRect(0,gridX,9000,2)
            let gridX1Color = NSColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0)
            let gridX1Path: NSBezierPath = NSBezierPath(rect: gridX1)
            gridX1Color.set()
            gridX1Path.fill()
            gridX = gridX + 20.0
        }

    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to my own question all that was needed was to create inside mySlider a CGPoint

```
let myPoint = CGPoint(x:Double(data),y:0.0)
```

then use

```
containerView.scroll(myPointer)
```

items to be removed not needed

```
    gridView.display()
    scrollbar.floatValue = Float(data!)
    scrollView.display()
    containerView.display()
```